# Make a thread that continues when program is stopped

Tags: python, multithreading, macos, python-2.x

Is it possible to make a thread that continues when the program is stopped?

When I first heard of daemonic threads, I thought that might be what I was after, but in fact they aren't what I need because I want the thread itself to carry on when the program is killed.

Comment: Is this on Unix/Linux?

Comment: A process is a container of threads.  A program is the code which is run in a process.   Do you mean process or program?

Comment: @MarcBalmer kinda, I am on macOS sierra (osx)

Comment: Ok, then you can not make that.  Threads are per process, so when the process terminates, all threads are terminated as well.  You best solution is probably to write a daemon() process.

Comment: @cdarke I don't know. I am facing a problem at the moment: a program I wrote is being run by another program, and this other program kills my program after 30 seconds. I want my program to persist, or at least part of it, after 30 seconds.

Comment: @MarcBalmer how would that work?

Comment: In C, you would call the daemon() function, a very simple approach it to start your program in the background, e.g. from the shell using $ start &.  For python, there is e.g. this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/daemonize/

Comment: Why were you talking about threads then?  What method is being used to kill your process?  If the other program is sending the SIGKILL signal (number 9) then there is no recovery, but the other program should not be doing that.  Preferably it should send a SIGTERM and you can then trap it.

Comment: @cdarke I don't know, I suspect it may be SIGKILL though. There must be a way to prevent it though; spawn a child process, schedule a task within the os to be run later, etc.

Comment: It seems to me that the original question was not the one the OP wanted to ask, and the real question has popped up in the comments. Perhaps it's time for a new question?

Comment: @mgarey yeah, done and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41416596/3310334